# Odd terminals splitting/panning - compared to IDEs/text editors

Tags: terminal, conemu

All terminals I've seen have odd (as for me) behavior about splitting. I expecting much from the new Windows Terminal, but they made this functionality as all terminals do, so I am wondering, is this some good idea and I just don't understand it.

What I am speaking about is they split inside each tab. And while splitting it duplicates the current console type.

What would I expect: like Visual Studio, VS Code, Notepad++, Sublime Text, and any other IDE/editor do. Split all working area and place tabs inside each pane.

Do I miss something? Does anyone think it should work like in editors too? Why was it made just the opposite ways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's usual behavior for terminals.

When you work with a visible area (a Tab) you use several panes, e.g. server log, build pane, client console.
This is most useable pattern I know.

If you want several consoles inside one pane - you may use any multiplexer (e.g. tmux) to achieve that.